# Spring 3.2 + Hibernate 4.2 : "The application must supply JDBC connections" - What is wrong with my configuration?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, configuration

I'm struggling to understand how to properly configure Spring 3.2 and Hibernate 4.2.  After working through several issues over the last few days, I ran into this exception while trying to execute a query in my DAO:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:62)
org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1426)
org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
com.bsj.demo.rest.dao.DemoUserDaoImpl.getAllDemoUsers(DemoUserDaoImpl.java:41)
```

Here are my Spring and Hibernate files:

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:spring/data-access.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/restdemo"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
             <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.bsj.demo.rest.*">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"  expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
</context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<context:spring-configured />
<context:annotation-config />
<bean class="com.bsj.demo.rest.spring.config.AppConfig"/>
</beans>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="RESTDemoJPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

What am I missing?  My understanding is that with Spring defining the datasource and persistence unit, there should be very little configuration needed in the persistence.xml.  Am I completely wrong here?

Server is Tomcat 7, dependencies managed by Maven.  I understand this is a commonly asked question on SO, but after trying several solutions I have not found a way to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured out the problem and it wasn't really related to configuration.  The problem was how I was instantiating the EntityManager in my code.

In the configuration, I needed to add the following to the entityManager bean definition:

`<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="RESTDemoJPA" />`

The bigger problem was that I was creating the EntityManager in each DAO by getting an instance from the EntityManagerFactory.  Instead, I should have been allowing Spring to inject it via the PersistenceContext annotation as follows:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="RESTDemoJPA")
private EntityManager em;
```

After doing that, I removed all calls to `em.getTransaction()`, annotated the class as `@Transactional` and the exceptions went away.  After that, I could query the database.

TL;DR: Configuration was correct minus defining the Persistence Unit name in the entityManager definition.  Changed EntityManager instantiation from manual to Spring injection.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look over here. Might be it can resolve your issue.

https://github.com/abdulwaheed18/Spring-HIbernate-Integration/blob/master/src/beans.xml